# Backpack for laravel - Guzzle instance error

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, laravel-backpack

I'm using backpack for laravel and one of my modules gives me an error when I try to initialize a web api class (Guzzle)... I have this code :

Controller

```
class ImportacionesCrudController extends CrudController
{
 protected $api;


  public function setup(webApi $api) {


  $this->api = $api;
  dd($this->api->sendValidation());
  }
}
```

And it instance this class:

```
namespace app\Api;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class webApi
{
protected cliente;

function __construct()
{
    #Se inicializa la conecccion al servicio web
    $client = new Client([
       // Base URI is used with relative requests
       'base_uri' => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
       // You can set any number of default request options.
       'timeout'  => 2.0,
    ]);

    $this->cliente = $client;

    #dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
}

public function sendValidation(){
    return $this->cliente->request('GET', 'posts');
}
}
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImportacionesCrudController::setup(App\Api\webApi $api) should be compatible with Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController::setup()
```

Any idea of what's wrong ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite the `setUp` method and add an argument, because the parent class doesn't take an argument in that method.  You can however do it in the constructor:

```
class ImportacionesCrudController extends CrudController
{
    private $api;

    public function __construct(webApi $api) {
        $this->api = $api;
        return parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->api->sendValidation();
        ....
```